# Facebook graph api no email in access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

while using facebook graph api in authenticating a user, after successful login, i want to get the user email.

For this, i raised a request for user data:
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx

But for my surprise, i could not get user's email in json output... 
how can i get the email ?
Do we need to specify any permissions ?

Comment: I think you can not get the email of user being authenticated

Comment: No yar, i could get email of some of the users easily, but for some users, iam unable to get. In the permissions screen itself, the email option does not show up. Is there a way to request permission for user's email ?

Comment: Please, can anyone help me here... iam not able to figure it out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes you do need permission to grab someone's email although some people have their privacy set so that you can get their emails without this expressed permission, most don't.

The permissions need to be set under the login section (it depends on how you login as to how it is presented, so I can't really help you out there unless I have more info).

'user_about_me' is the user permission that you probably already have but you need 'email' to get their primary email.

More information on the permissions for facebook developers can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions).

I hope this has helped!

Best of luck,

Jon

Comment: Hi, i could get the user email now, by requesting a permission in my graph api request, by adding: scope=email at the end of my request. :)

Comment: @dskanth: so was the answer helpful? if so, then accept it..otherwise add a new answer with the solution and accept your own answer.

Comment: So I have 'email' in the permissions string but for like .1% of my users no email is allowed through their access token. I've confirmed this in the graph api explorer.

Answer (score 8):

You have to force it, like this:
`...graph.facebook.com/me?**fields=email,name**&access_token...`
Then you can use the object *user->email*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to ask permission for email.
If you already ask email in the request and still you are not getting email id on the response then it is due to user sign up with mobile number and didn't enter his email id in profile.